# Is it possible to autocomplete the name of an executable in `cmd`?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

In Windows 10, I have added the path of an executable into `Path`.

In `cmd`, when I try to type just some beginning characters of the name of the executable, and hit tab, the shell doesn't autocomplete the name of the executable.

Is it possible to autocomplete the name of an executable in `cmd`? I do that all the time under bash.

Thanks.

Comment: "Is it possible to autocomplete the name of an executable in cmd?"  Yes, but Windows' autocomplete is based on the current directory, and does not autocomplete commands available on the path.

Comment: Interesting. I tried another way. I run emacs in cmd. In emacs, I run a shell which runs cmd, which can do autocomplete using `Path`. Is the autocompletion done by emacs instead of cmd?

Comment: For what it's worth, PowerShell does autocomplete EXEs on the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell does this out of the box. If you install the PSReadline module you can configure it so it behaves pretty much identically to bash. (It actually works better than bash in some ways.)